# Postgresql Update not updating, query finish successfully

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do this:

```
api-prod::DATABASE=> SELECT winner from factoring_bid WHERE id = 16184;
 winner 
--------
 f
(1 row)

api-prod::DATABASE=> SELECT winner from factoring_bid WHERE id = 16184;
 winner 
--------
 f
(1 row)

api-prod::DATABASE=> UPDATE factoring_bid set winner = 't' WHERE id=16184;
UPDATE 1
api-prod::DATABASE=> SELECT winner from factoring_bid WHERE id = 16184;
 winner 
--------
 f
(1 row)
```

Update seems to work fine, but any change in this register (and some others) are not really happening. And yes, the user running this query has write permissions.

More info:

- This is a Heroku postgresql database.
- Updating some other registers on factoring_bid table works just fine.
- factoring_bid table is related to another table called factoring_auction. All factoring_bid's related to the factoring_auction of the example have the same problem. Can't be updated.
- factoring_bids related to other auctions have no problem. Maybe my application (a Django Rest Framework API) introduced some error in the bids of this specific auction?, I can't think of anything, but seems weird that they are related.
- We don't use locks, there seems to be no lock running on the database currently.

Comment: Is there a connection pooler involved? pgbouncer, pgpool?

Comment: Was looking for heroku official documentation is case of some connection pool is set as default (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-connection-pooling) but no, it's not activated at the moment.

Comment: Any hints from the database logs?  This seems awfully strange--a typical occurrence of this would involve a connection pooler, where you are sometimes unknowingly using separate sessions and therefore different row visibility.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, richyen. I've never worked with connection pools, is  it normal that an UPDATE query finish with that successful message "UPDATE 1" when working with connection pools?. About the logs, we haven't seen anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: It's normal that you see `UPDATE 1`, but not normal that the update doesn't actually happen.  I can't think of any other situation where this would happen, and I'd like to see what the real answer is, if anyone else wants to contribute here. What if you issue a `COMMIT` between the `UPDATE` and the last `SELECT`? And and does the txid change when you issue `SELECT txid_current()` several times?

Comment: Does this happen for `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s too?